# How to get a new pid file of Mysql and restart Mysql Successfully?

Tags: mysql, linux, centos

Due to `lost of pid file of my server`, I can't stop mysql using normal commands like

```
service mysql stop
```

which will show

```
ERROR! MySQL server PID file could not be found!
```

So I try to stop all mysql processes and restart mysql mannually

I've searched the Internet and found one solution, but it doesn't work for me.

I run

```sh
ps aux | grep mysql
```

and the result shows

```
root      6490  0.0  0.2 112720  2332 pts/0    S+   03:48   0:00 grep --color=auto mysql
```

So I type

```
kill -9 6490
```

but the result is

```
-bash: kill: (6490) - No such process
```

It seems every time I try to kill it, the pid changes.

How can I really stop all mysql processes? Then **be able to get a new pid file**? New to linux and mysql, thank you in advance!

---

#### Update:

Thanks to Henryk Gerlach's answer, it seems I have shut down all Mysql processes, but after I restart my server the pid file doesn't auto-generate. How should I do to really make my Mysql back to normal??

Comment: If ode2k's suggestions with `service mysql stop` don't work (or, on a more modern centos, `systemctl stop mysql (the name may be different, don't have centos to check)` ...

Answer (score 1):

The result you are showing:

```
root      6490  0.0  0.2 112720  2332 pts/0    S+   03:48   0:00 grep --color=auto mysql
```

is actually the pid and process for the  `ps aux | grep mysql` command. It is not actually a process for MySQL.

A running process for MySQL would look similar to this:

```
mysql     1894  0.8  9.8 1865804 1192032 ?     Sl   Jul01 300:53 /usr/sbin/mysqld --basedir=/usr --datadir=/var/lib/mysql --plugin-dir=/usr/lib64/mysql/plugin --user=mysql --log-error=/var/lib/mysql/DBNAME.err --pid-file=/var/lib/mysql/DBNAME.pid
```

You can use the command `pkill` to kill the running MySQL processes by name. However, it's not recommended to kill MySQL in a forceful manner.

```
 pkill -f mysql
```

This will match the filename pattern for any part of the command line

To start/stop the MySQL services, you can run:

```
service mysqld start 
service mysqld stop 
service mysqld restart
```

or

```
service mysql start
service mysql stop
service mysql restart
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! But after I do this, I run `ps aux | grep mysql`, the mysql process still show up. It seems it will respawn at any time.

Comment: Updated with some more relevant information. Looks like your remaining process isn't actually MySQL

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But actually, I'm using this method to help me fix my problem of missing Mysql pid file, so every time I'm using commands like `service mysql stop`, the result is `ERROR! MySQL server PID file could not be found!`, I'm sorry if the question confuces you.

Comment: Your MySQL pid file is missing in the instance above because it isn't actually running anymore. The line that is showing up in your `ps aux | grep mysql` shows the pid of the `ps aux | grep mysql` command, not the `mysql` database service process. If you start up your database, then run that command, you will see the difference.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
ps aux > /tmp/processes
grep mysql /tmp/processes
```

If the grep does not return anything then no mysql is running.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I don't see any results.